# print multiple number format with python that make column counts greater than row

Tags: python

how write one function that accecpt one parameter(number), and print format like this with python

```
1  2   3   4   5    6    7     8     9     10
x  xx  xx  xx  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx   xxx   xxxx
       x   xx  xx   xxx  xxx  xxx   xxx   xxxx
                         x    xx    xxx   xx 
1  
out:
x  

input:
2
out:
xx

input:
3
xx     
x

input:
4
out:
xx
xx

input:
5
out:
xxx
xx
```

I can't summary any formula to handle this solution, may be it's one math question.

**Note the answer**
ok， I solve it myself, but I think this method is stupid.

```
import sys

def fun(num):
    column_count = 1

    for i in range(num):
        # once column_count's  square > i, columns + 1
        if column_count **2 == i:
            column_count += 1

    for i in range(num + 1):
        if i % column_count == 0:
            sys.stdout.write('x\n')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('x')

    sys.stdout.flush()

fun(10)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `string.format` / `zip_longest` solution

```
import itertools
import math

def crosses(n):
    format = n * '{!r:4}  '
    numbers = list(range(1, n+1))
    print(format.format(*numbers))
    format = len(numbers) * '{:4}  '
    for f in itertools.zip_longest(
            *((min(mn, c)*'x' for mn, c in zip(
                itertools.repeat(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))),
                range(n, 0, -math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))))
              for n in numbers),
            fillvalue=''):
        print(format.format(*f))

crosses(10)
```

prints:

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    
x     xx    xx    xx    xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx   xxxx  
            x     xx    xx    xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx   xxxx  
                                    x     xx    xxx   xx
```

It uses format strings to manage the white space. Apart from that it's a simple loop over lines with inner looping over numbers managed by zipped generators. The modified format string used for the header uses `!r` to sidestep the normal right aligned formatting of ints.

Comment: @KillPillar Ah, I didn't notice the changing column width earlier. I've updated the answer. Have a look. I hope the difference in spacings is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through while a count is less than number and if count % 4 == 0, print ("\n") else print ("x",end="").

```
count = 0
while count < number:
    if count % 4 == 0:
        print("\n")
    print("x",end="")
```

And just put everything aboveboard in your function.
I hope this helps. I did a similar question for the CCC just yesterday. I had to make it print out a month timetable like with all the rows and such.

Comment: just set up one number, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9 and print the corresponding format

Comment: With this code, every element will be on its own line, with a blank line separating each group.

Comment: No it will not be?